# Auth0->Atlassian SAML SSO Problem (SP Entity and ACS URL)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, auth0

So I'm trying to integrate single sign-on with Auth0 (being both the service provider and the identity provider) with the Atlassian stack.

Atlassian offer SAML single sign-on. However, it is telling me:

```
Your users won't be able to log in with SAML single sign-on until you've copied 
the values for SP Entity ID and SP Assertion Consumer Service URL to your 
identity provider.
```

I've put the assertion consumer service URL in place of the callback URL, I've done some research and I'm almost certain this is correct.

However, the issue is with the Entity ID. Where does this go?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Auth0 before, but I think you have to set it as `audience` in the settings, e.g. see https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-apps/heroku
IMHO but the configuration option is a bit misleading. Instead of using `audience`, using `EntityID` might be clearer, as this is also the term used in the SAML spec.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that auth0 acting as a service provider.

Assertions Consumer service URL should be :

```
https://YOUR_DOMAIN/login/callback?connection=YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Entity ID of the service provider should be:

```
urn:auth0:YOUR_TENANT:YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME
```

You can download service provider metadata like below in the XML format and upload to IDP to generate configuration.

Navigate to https://YOUR_DOMAIN/samlp/metadata?connection=YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME

Additional:

> URI: `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity` Indicates that
>   the content of the element is the identifier of an entity that
>   provides SAML-based services (such as a SAML authority) or is a
>   participant in SAML profiles (such as a service provider supporting
>   the browser SSO profiles). Such an identifier can be used in the
>    element to identify the issuer of a SAML request, response,
>   or assertion, or within the  element to make assertions about
>   system entities that can issue SAML requests, responses, and
>   assertions. It can also be used in other elements and attributes whose
>   purpose is to identify a system entity in various protocol exchanges.
>   The syntax of such an identifier is a URI of not more than 1024
>   characters in length. It is RECOMMENDED that a system entity use a URL
>   containing its own domain name to identify itself
>   (SAML CORE specification, section 8.3.6)
>   https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/7473/sstc-saml-core-2.0-draft-15-diff.pdf
>   https://spaces.at.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/Entity+IDs